# Connecting a signal to a pin in Quartus

Tags: signal, wire, pins, quartus, intel

I want to connect a signal in a .v file to a top level pin assigned in the pin planner but I've no idea where to start. I've looked at several guides but as a C programmer this is all quite alien to me.

Answer (score 0):

The pin planner has a list of all ports defined in the toplevel design element, taken from compilation output. You compile once, get a somewhat random assignment of pins, then modify that in the pin planner.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is though as the .v file isn't the top level file, the signal name doesn't appear in the assignment list and I can't rename the pins as they are read only apparently. I suppose the main issue is I'm modifying an existing open source project

Comment: Do I just define the signal name in the top level file then compile and assign?

Comment: @JoelWhybrow, there is no top-level file, just a top-level component. All files are treated the same, and the project configuration says which component is top-level. Pin names and directions are taken from the externally visible pins of that component.